# Markdown with Shiny not working on Mac. Error: path for html_dependency not provided Execution halted

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, twitter-r

I'm new to Shiny and I was just trying to see what's the result gonna look like and test out different data sets. I entered the code provided by Diego Lescano, you can find the full script here, http://datascienceplus.com/how-to-create-a-twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-r-and-shiny/

Everything ran through smoothly, however I wasn't able to see the final graph when I tried to knit. Instead, I received the following warning

> output file: Final_Project.knit.md
>
> Error: path for html_dependency not provided
>
> Execution halted

I tried to knit to pdf and word as well, it all failed. Here's what my output looked like

> output:
>     html_document: default

Comment: This is a Shiny app, which you'd run either using `runApp()`, or the run app button within RStudio.  It wouldn't knit to pdf or html as it isn't an Rmarkdown document, hence the error.